# (Code Review) Java if statement involving logical and(&&) operator

Tags: java, android

I have started programming a few weeks ago in java/android. I want to write a small tic tac toe game as an android app but I'm having trouble with my method that will check for the winner. It is as follows:

```
 public void checkForWinner() { 

        if( taken[0] && taken[3] && taken[6]  ||
            taken[0] && taken[1] && taken[2] ||
            taken[2] && taken[5] && taken[8] ||
            taken[6] && taken[7] && taken[8] ||
            taken[0] && taken[4] && taken[8] ||
            taken[2] && taken[4] && taken[6] ||
            taken[1] && taken[4] && taken[7] ||
            taken[3] && taken[4] && taken[5] == 1 ){}
}
```

Here I have an array called taken that holds 9 integers, each of those integers being either a one, meaning player one owns that block, or a two, meaning player two ows that block. Current, I am trying trying all possible scenarios in which player one would be the winner but eclipse is telling me that `The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) int, int`. The error only seems to be showing for the first logical and operation of each line of the if statement. For example the first error goes up to `taken[0] && taken[3]` and then disappears until the next line.

Comment: If there are only two possible values in the elements of the array 'taken' then you should consider creating a boolean array instead, this way your logical statements also make sense though you may want to add parenthesis for readability.  However, seeing as you are trying to implement a tic-tac-toe game you will need another value for a space that has neither a '1' or a '2' and in this case you will need to check for equality using '==', not the boolean operators.

Comment: Boolean array is a bad idea, as you need three states. Empty, p1, p2.

Comment: @Sam [Nah you're not open enough](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx) ;)

Comment: Boolean array is not a bad idea, as long as it is the Boolean object and not the primitive, however, you have to be aware of that when checking it's contents that it could be null (for an empty block).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you can check taken[n] values to see if they hold 1 or 2, if you think that'd make your code clearer:

```
(taken[0]==1 && taken[3]==1 && taken[6]==1)
```

Keep in mind that the && operator expects boolean operands...so it won't work with your int array the way you're expecting it to.

Comment: Oh, this works, i thought i could check the boolean expression at the end of the statement, i guess I'll check them seperately for now. Thanks

Comment: The downside with doing the check this way is that you will need two almost identical conditional checks causing a large amount of repeated code. Though if you modify the method to accept an integer equivalent to the player number, and swap the hardcoded 1 or 2 to the parameter it would reduce that extra code.

Answer (score 2):

Swap your && to ==, you're trying to see if they're all the same value I assume which would show a winner, and be sure to use parentheses to sort it out, so one win condition would look like

```
((taken[0] == taken[3]) && (taken[0] == taken[6]))
```

However, this will only tell you that some player won, not which player. I guess you could check to see which player made the last move once it is determined that some one has won and declare that player as the winner.

Comment: `taken[0] == taken[3]` returns a boolean. `(boolean result) == taken[6]` is invalid.

Comment: You're completely correct, a bit disappointed that I let it slip my mind that easily, I'll edit so the information isn't invalid.

Answer (score 1):

In java,

```
if (a && b) or if (a || b)
```

works only if a and b are booleans / boolean expressions.

Answer (score 1):

1) You cant use `&&` or `||` operators on `int` variables because the are meant for `boolean` values.

2) also use brackets to group conditions like

```
 if (
      (taken[0]==1 && taken[3]==1 && taken[6]==1)||
      (taken[0]==1 && taken[1]==1 && taken[2]==1)||
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here I have an array called taken that holds 9 integers, each of those integers being either a one, meaning player one owns that block, or a two, meaning player two owns that block.

In that case, you can replace the logical operators with bitwise operators:

```
int winner = taken[0] & taken[3] & taken[6]
           | taken[0] & taken[1] & taken[2]
           | taken[2] & taken[5] & taken[8]
           | taken[6] & taken[7] & taken[8]
           | taken[0] & taken[4] & taken[8]
           | taken[2] & taken[4] & taken[6]
           | taken[1] & taken[4] & taken[7]
           | taken[3] & taken[4] & taken[5];
```

Then the variable `winner` will contain 1 if player 1 won, 2 if player 2 won, 0 if neither of them won, or 3 of both of them won (which probably isn't possible in your game).

Comment: Wow, this is a much simpler method of doing this and it works exactly the same way as i had it before. Thank you.

Comment: Note that his only works because 1 and 2 are powers of two. If you ever add a third player to the game, you must encode him as 4, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

OK there are two main problems here.

First, `taken[0]` needs to return either true or false to be able to remain as-is within the if-statement. You have mentioned it is an integer, so for it to return true or false, you'll need to do a comparison, such as `taken[0] == 1`.

Second, you need to use parentheses and do some groupings. Java does not respect whitespace. Instead of `if( taken[0] && taken[3] && taken[6]  || ...`, you'll need to do `if( (taken[0] && taken[3] && taken[6])  || ...`. That is, you need to put parentheses around each set of groupings.

The reason Eclipse is erroring is because the `&&` operator is only for comparing booleans. That is `true && true`. You're giving it integers and it doesn't like that.

One way you might want to solve this is to write a function that determines if a solution is reached. So maybe something like:

```
private boolean isSolutionPresent(int[] taken, int index1, int index2, int index3) {
    return (taken[index1] == 1 ) && (taken[index2] == 1) && (taken[index3] == 1);
}
```

Then you could convert your if statement to something like:

```
if (isSolutionPresent(taken, 0, 3, 6) ||
    isSolutionPresent(taken, 0, 1, 2) ||
    isSolutionPresent(taken, 2, 5, 8) || //... etc, removing the final ==1
```

Since the `isSolutionPresent` method returns a boolean (that is, true/false) you can apply the `||` operator to it.

Comment: Your 'isSolutionPresent' is not going to work. the `==` operator returns a boolean, and then you're trying to compare that boolean result to an int.

Comment: What int are you talking about? There are only booleans in the if-statement.

Comment: `taken[index1] == taken[index2] == taken[index3] == 1;`. int == int, return boolean. boolean == int, compilation fail.

Comment: Removed my downvote, but the boolean array is also a bad idea. There's at least three states in a tic-tac-toe game, empty, X, or O.

Comment: Yes, I removed that. On the other hand, a `Boolean[]` array would work, even though the `null` `Boolean` state is probably not a good way to go.